# Best practice for alerts if webpage returns white page?

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, monitoring

We're trying to setup monitoring (zabbix), for webapps that return white page of death. Apps are PHP based.

From what I know, white screen of death can be caused by number of issues, memory issues, syntax errors etc.

So I want to ask, is it better to rely on webserver returning 50x code, or there can be (somehow) posibility to get return code 200, but rendering page is empty(white) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on HTTP status codes is best and commonly used practice. If PHP runs into critical errors it should shut down with an appropriate HTTP error code.

A critical error with a HTTP status code 200 is bogus claim and should be avoided. Even nicely designed 404 pages should use the HTTP error code 404 and nothing else.

Using HTTP error codes you are able to:

- use existing online and on-premises monitoring tools to monitor your Web sites and apps
- allow browsers to react according to the given error
- tell Google and other search engines that you have an error instead of new content within your website
- configure Nginx to show proper HTML and keep the error code if your PHP shuts down with a fatal error

  ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correctly monitor a web site, you should identify a string or strings that appear in your web content and have your monitor check that those strings exist in the HTTP response.

If you are running a web application that collects and processes form data, you should create an interactive monitor that processes forms and confirms that the form is returning the correct result. You can do this in a variety of ways. In the past I've integrated Jmeter with Nagios to do this, but you can also use online services likes Pingdom.

Relying on HTTP status codes isn't in my opinion good practice. A DB error in PHP could still return a HTTP 200 status. Similarly, a site that has been defaced could return a 200 status code.

https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Java-Applications-and-Servers/jmeter-invocation-plugin-II/details

https://www.pingdom.com/

Comment: Db errors (fatal ones ) should give 500 on webserver, unless you've mean on programming error, f.e. query returning an empty set. Then there might be code 200, but those are impossible to catch, on this level, that should be developers job to handle (if result is unexpected).

Comment: That's a fair point, but given the myriad issues that can arise with a web site these days, I think relying exclusively on status codes is misguided. There's a good reason why services like Pingdom rely on response assertions as well as status codes.